# Hibernate createSQLQuery giving exception - String index out of range: 0

Tags: hibernate

For the below mentioned logic implemented get exception (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0) at line : result = q.list();

I know for sure that the gender is null at many places. Is there any other alternative to check for null while querying?

```
 beginTransaction();
        try {
            SQLQuery q = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " +
                                                     "ind.ind_id AS id, " +
                                                     "ind.IND_FNAME AS firstName, " +
                                                     "ind.IND_LNAME AS lastName, " +
                                                     "perInfo.IND_DOB AS dob, " +
                                                     "trc.trCTM_Grade_Mapping AS grade, " +
                                                     "TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, perInfo.IND_DOB, NOW()) AS years, " +
                                                     "TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, perInfo.IND_DOB, NOW())  AS months, " +
                                                     "perInfo.IND_SEX AS sex " +
                                                         "FROM INDIVIDUALS ind " +
                                                             "INNER JOIN USER_MEMBERSHIPS usm on usm.USR_ID = ind.IND_ID " +
                                                             "INNER JOIN PERSONAL_INFO perInfo on perInfo.IND_ID = ind.IND_ID " +
                                                             "INNER JOIN TRACKER_CUSTOM_DASHBOARD trcd on perInfo.IND_ID = trcd.USR_ID  " +
                                                             "INNER JOIN TRACKER_CUSTOM trc on trcd.trCTM_MainID = trc.trCTM_MainID " +
                                                         "WHERE usm.GRP_ID = :GRP_ID ;");


            q.setInteger ("GRP_ID", groupId);
            q.setResultTransformer (Transformers.aliasToBean (ImmunizationsComplianceDTO.class));
            result = q.list();
        }catch(RuntimeException e) {
            rollbackTransaction();
            handleHibernateException(e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            closeTransaction();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ImmunizationsComplianceDTO I did make follwoing changes. Still no luck got same issue...

Instead of simply adding getter and setter, Added a null check for gender

```
 if(gender != null){
                this.sex = gender;
            }
```

Complete getter setter is shown below.

```
// Getter setter for gender of the student.
    public Character getSex() {
        return sex;
    }
    public void setSex(Character gender) {
        if(gender != null){
            this.sex = gender;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the sex / gender column had nulls and to overcome that issue added the following in the query

```
"COALESCE(perInfo.IND_SEX, '') AS sex" +
```

So the final query looks like

```
beginTransaction();
        try {
            SQLQuery q = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " +
                                                     "ind.ind_id AS id, " +
                                                     "ind.IND_FNAME AS firstName, " +
                                                     "ind.IND_LNAME AS lastName, " +
                                                     "perInfo.IND_DOB AS dob, " +
                                                     "trc.trCTM_Grade_Mapping AS grade, " +
                                                     "TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, perInfo.IND_DOB, NOW()) AS years, " +
                                                     "TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, perInfo.IND_DOB, NOW())  AS months, " +
                             "COALESCE(perInfo.IND_SEX, '') AS gender" + 
                                                         "FROM INDIVIDUALS ind " +
                                                             "INNER JOIN USER_MEMBERSHIPS usm on usm.USR_ID = ind.IND_ID " +
                                                             "INNER JOIN PERSONAL_INFO perInfo on perInfo.IND_ID = ind.IND_ID " +
                                                             "INNER JOIN TRACKER_CUSTOM_DASHBOARD trcd on perInfo.IND_ID = trcd.USR_ID  " +
                                                             "INNER JOIN TRACKER_CUSTOM trc on trcd.trCTM_MainID = trc.trCTM_MainID " +
                                                         "WHERE usm.GRP_ID = :GRP_ID ;");


            q.setInteger ("GRP_ID", groupId);
            q.setResultTransformer (Transformers.aliasToBean (ImmunizationsComplianceDTO.class));
            result = q.list();
        }catch(RuntimeException e) {
            rollbackTransaction();
            handleHibernateException(e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            closeTransaction();
        }
```